# React form not filling out with fetched data

Tags: reactjs

I am currently building a react application with a .net core back end. My current issue lies in a view that is meant to edit an article (which is made up of only a title and description). On `componentDidMount`, I am getting the route param id from the route and retrieving the article from the server with it (I've verified that this works correctly). My issue is that my form is not filling out with the fetched data. I'm of the understanding that since the form fields set to `this.state...` then they should update as the state updates however this is not what I'm seeing. I believe the issue is may lie with the warning I'm receiving in console:

> index.js:2177 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of
>   type hidden to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from
>   controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a
>   controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
>   component.

I've read the documentation the warning points to and am not seeing how my component violates this.

My component is below in full:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CKEditor from 'react-ckeditor-component';

export class ArticlesEdit extends Component {
  displayName = ArticlesEdit.name

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        title: '',
        description: ''
     };

     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

   componentDidMount () {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    fetch(`https://localhost:44360/api/articles/${id}`)
      .then((article) => {
        this.setState({
            title: article.title,
            description: article.description
        });
      });
  }

  updateDescription(event){
    this.setState({description: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <div className="form-group row" >  
                    <label className=" control-label col-md-12" htmlFor="Title">Title</label>  
                    <div className="col-md-4">  
                        <input className="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" defaultValue={this.state.title} required />  
                    </div>  
                </div >    
                <CKEditor activeClass="editor" content={this.state.description} events= {{"change": this.onEditorChange.bind(this) }} />
                <input type="hidden" id="description" name="description" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.updateDescription}/>
                <div className="form-group">  
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Save</button>  
                </div >  
            </form >  
      );
  }

  onEditorChange(evt){
    var newContent = evt.editor.getData();
    this.setState({
      description: newContent
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {  
    event.preventDefault();  
    const data = new FormData(event.target);  

    console.log(this.state.title);
    // POST request for Add employee.  
        fetch('https://localhost:44360/api/articles/', {  
            method: 'PUT',  
            body: data
        }).then((response) => response.json())  
            .then((responseJson) => {  
                this.props.history.push("/articles");  
            })  

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing the JSON you get as response to your fetch in `componentDidMount`. If you add `.then((response) => response.json())` it should work as expected.

```js
componentDidMount () {
  const { id } = this.props.match.params;

  fetch(`https://localhost:44360/api/articles/${id}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((article) => {
      this.setState({
        title: article.title,
        description: article.description
      });
    });
}
```

You also need to use the `value` prop instead of the `defaultValue` prop on your input so that it will have the value of `title` in your state.

```js
<input
  className="form-control"
  type="text" id="title"
  name="title"
  value={this.state.title}
  required
/>
```